# Syntax Error @date1

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT FactOrders.TerritoryKey ,
       FactOrders.DistributorKey ,
       FactOrders.ItemKey ,
       SUM(FactOrders.UnitQty)as Quantity ,
       SUM(FactOrders.GrossValue) as Gross_Value 
FROM FactOrders 
WHERE FactOrders.TerritoryKey = @TerritoryKey and 
      FactOrders.DistributorKey = @DistributorKey and 
      FactOrders.DateKey >=CInt(Format(Paramters!@Date1.Value,"yyyyMMdd")) and 
      FactOrders.DateKey <= @Date2 AND 
      FactOrders.LineType = 'ORDER' 
GROUP BY FactOrders.TerritoryKey , FactOrders.DistributorKey ,FactOrders.ItemKey 
ORDER BY FactOrders.TerritoryKey , FactOrders.DistributorKey ,FactOrders.ItemKey
```

---

Comment: `@Date1` looks like a variable, but did you define it anywhere?  Why are you trying to access a property?

Comment: @ Date1 is a paramter in my ms sql report writer.  It is Date type parameter. I want to convert it to intiger.

Comment: @DumindaAthuraliyaPathegama Date1 =2017-01-31 means on what basis u need to convert into int

Comment: @Chanukya I want to convert 5/21/2016 to 20160521 . because in data base date use as integer. but in parameter section I want to use it as date type.

Comment: @Chanukya Now It gives "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 5/21/2016 to data type int  , Error 245

Comment: @DumindaAthuraliyaPathegama check now i edited my answer

Comment: @chanukya Thank you, It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried like this just check it

```
SELECT FactOrders.TerritoryKey ,
       FactOrders.DistributorKey ,
       FactOrders.ItemKey ,
       SUM(FactOrders.UnitQty)as Quantity ,
       SUM(FactOrders.GrossValue) as Gross_Value 
FROM FactOrders 
WHERE FactOrders.TerritoryKey = @TerritoryKey and 
      FactOrders.DistributorKey = @DistributorKey and 
     ---- FactOrders.DateKey >=CInt(Format(Paramters!@Date1.Value,"yyyyMMdd")) and
     CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST(@date1 AS DATE),112)
      FactOrders.DateKey <= @Date2 AND 
      FactOrders.LineType = 'ORDER' 
GROUP BY FactOrders.TerritoryKey , FactOrders.DistributorKey ,FactOrders.ItemKey 
ORDER BY FactOrders.TerritoryKey , FactOrders.DistributorKey ,FactOrders.ItemKey
```